# deploying client and server code to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, nestjs

I have a code base that looks as follows:

```
rootfolder
    -- backend
    -- frontend
    -- .git
```

the **.git** folder hence the entire version control is located in **rootfolder**,
each subfolder (**backend** and **frontend**) has a **package.json** and a **package.lock** file

the backend project is a NestJs App

the fronted  project is an Angular App

in order to serve the client files I've designated **/** route of my backend app to serve static files, those files are the compiled version of my frontend

in localhost it works like a charm, the thing comes when deploying to Heroku

I have CI/CD pipelines that automate this task but they fail because Heroku cant detect a package.json file in **rootfolder**

I would just need to run my server (inside **backend** folder) to spin up my entire App
is there a way to point Heroku where the package.json file is? Or to make it step on the right directory?

the problem originates because with the CI/CD pipeline I'm pushing the entire **rootfolder**
Idk if I should push only my server app with the static client files, I would like to not get rid of the CI/CD pipelines if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyone out there sill wandering the same there is a script provided by heroku where you can run logic prior to building process

In my case I've created a **package.json** file at **rootfolder** level with the following scripts

```
 "scripts": {
"heroku-prebuild": "(cd ./backend && npm install && npm run build && cd ../frontend && npm install && npm run build:frontend)",
 "start": "(cd ./backend && npm run start)",
}
```

with `heroku-prebuild` command I could cd into mi **backend** protect folder then build it, then cd into my **frontend** protect folder, and then run my custom `build:frontend` command which compiles my frontend app and then puts it inside a designated folder in my backend project to be served as static files for my backend